# Alipne.js total not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, xcode, undefined-behavior, alpine.js

I have a simple program that shows wordpress post and loads depending on category click.

I was following this tutorial (second part) https://joeyfarruggio.com/wordpress/skeleton-loader/

Ive had a few bugs along the way but solved most.

I have one bug left, I am getting

> cdn.min.js:1 Alpine Expression Error: total is not defined

Expression: "total > (limit + offset)"

div.text-center.mt-12_x_attributeCleanups:

in the console and cant work out why

this is my current code, the error above is the only error im getting.

```
<?php /* Template Name: test */ 
?>
<html>
<head>
     <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
     <script>

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: null,
    category: null,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    loadingNew: false, // <--- defaults to false
    loadingMore: false, // <--- defaults to false
    offset: 0,

    filterPosts(id) {
        this.loadingNew = true;
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    
    loadMore() {
        this.loadingMore = true;
        this.offset += 10;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
    },

    fetchPosts(append = false) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("offset", this.offset); // <-- Add new data to the form
        // formData.append("limit", this.limit);

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
        }

        fetch(adminURL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
        
      .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            if (append) {
                // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
            } else {
                // Resets the posts data with new data
                this.posts = res.posts;
            }
            
                this.loading = false;
             // Reset both loading states
            // this.loadingNew = false;
            // this.loadingMore = false;
         
        });
    },
    
    getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
    });
},

init() {
    this.getTotal();
}
}));
})

    
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div x-data="filterPosts('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>')">
        
        
<section <?php theme_section_attr_id() ?> <?php theme_section_attr_class('main-section js-posts') ?>>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading mx-0">
      <?php $before_title = get_sub_field('before_title');
      if ($before_title) : ?>
        <strong class="sub-title"><?php echo $before_title ?></strong>
      <?php endif ?>
      <?php $title = get_sub_field('title');
      if ($title) : ?>
        <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div>

      <!--<div class="head js-posts-search-text">-->
      <!--  <?php if ($search_value) : ?>-->
      <!--    <h2 class="h5 fw-semibold"><?php printf(__('Showing results for “%s”', 'base'), $search_value) ?></h2>-->
      <!--  <?php endif ?>-->
      <!--</div>-->
      
<!--alipne js dynamic post start-->
    <div class="has-filter row flex-md-row-reverse">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 js-posts-holder">
                <!-- Posts Column -->
            <div x-show.important="showDefault" class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                <!-- Default posts query -->
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/default-query' ); ?>
                 <!-- Load More Posts -->
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button 
                            @click="loadMore()" 
                            x-show="total > (limit + offset)"
                            class="bg-white border border-solid border-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-100 px-4 py-2">
                            Load More</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
           
            
                <!-- Filtered posts -->
            <div x-show.important="showFiltered" x-html="posts" class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                <!-- Default posts query -->
            </div>
            
            <!-- Skeleton Loader -->
    <template x-if="loadingNew || loadingMore">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
            <template x-for="i in 4">
                <div>
                    <div class="h-52 w-full bg-slate-200 rounded-lg"></div>
                    <div class="h-8 w-1/2 bg-slate-200 rounded-lg mt-4"></div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
    </div>
            
        <!-- Filtered posts -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
             <aside class="sidebar">
                 <div class="widget widget-filter">
                     <button class="widget-title">Explore Topics</button>
                     <svg class="separator" viewBox="0 0 238 11" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <line opacity="0.3" y1="0.5" x2="101.942" y2="0.5" stroke="#3CD5AF"></line>
                <line opacity="0.3" y1="10.5" x2="237.5" y2="10.5" stroke="#3CD5AF"></line>
              </svg>
            <?php 
                $categories = get_categories();
                if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) : 
            ?>
            <ul class="filter-list">
                <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
                
                // Skip "Uncategorized" category
                if ($category->name == 'Uncategorized') continue; ?>    
        
                   <li :class=" category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? '' : ''">
            <a hreff="" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html( $category->name ); ?></button>
        </li>
                
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
</aside>
        <!-- Filtered end -->
          </div>   
    </div>
    </div>
<!--alipne js dynamic post end-->

</section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must define the *total* and *limit* variables in the *filterPosts* object

Comment: @Pippo as in Alpine.data("filterPosts","total", (adminURL) => ({ ?

Comment: No, in the same place of: `posts: null, category: null, ....`

Comment: @Pippo, have updated my code, not sure I have done it correct

Comment: so set total:null and limit: null in the first function ?

Comment: I can't see the suggeted modification, I add an answer that should be more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using the *total* and *limit* variables but they are not defined as Alpine properties.

To fix it you need to change as follows:

```js
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({

    total: 0,  // <<<< ADD THIS
    limit: 0,  // <<<< AND THIS
    posts: null,
    category: null,

    .....
```

I have not tested the code logic which I assume is correct...

Comment: cheers @pippo, been a total noob today. thank you